# Editor with Maths functions . generating file

Tags: html, editor

I am using math editor in web page. but it's generating jpeg file.  not able to write in doc or other file . there is any change in javascipt file or php file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy and paste the text from wiris into word and modify the equation in word. I wouldn't download the file as an image. Just copy and paste it into word.

Comment: its wiris editor . which is saving jpg file only  i want it in editable file

Comment: Please check some additional options to copy-paste to and from WIRIS at http://www.wiris.com/editor/docs/manual/copy-paste